# Comparing columns uptill certain index in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to compare two columns (dep and label)and set an entry in the third column(mark) only if 'dep' has match in 'label' for previous index values. For example, in the following example, 'label=40' (id =2, has dep=45) but we set mark as 2 because the matching label (45) exist later (id=4 or 8). Also, if there are multiple matches, we keep the recent one. For example, label 52 (id 9) is dependent on 45, so pick the id of most recent match which is id 8. Also, I do not want a comparison when dep <1

```
library(data.table)
trace <- data.table(id=1:10, dep=c(-1,45,40,47,0,45,43,42,45,45), 
label=c(99,40,43,45,47,42,48,45,52,67), mark=rep("",10))
   id dep label mark
1:  1  -1    99  1    
2:  2  45    40  2  
3:  3  40    43  2   
4:  4  47    45  4  
5:  5  0     47  5   
6:  6  45    42  4  
7:  7  43    48  3
8:  8  42    45  6   
9:  9  45    52  8  
10: 10  45   67  8
```

The loop solution for this would be

```
trace$mark <- trace$id
for (i in 1:length(trace$id)){
    val <- trace$dep[i]
    j <- 1
while(j<=i && val >1){ 
    if(val==trace$label[j]){
        trace$mark[i] <- trace$id[j]
                }
   j <-j +1
 }
}
```

A following solution which was suggested earlier here sets all values whether they occur before or after the current index.

```
trace[trace[dep>1,.(id,dep=label)],mark:=i.id,on="dep"]
```

Any idea how to accomplish this

Comment: Your loop solution doesn't return anything. What is the desired output?

Comment: @DavidA It's the mark column displayed at top.. I think.

Comment: @Frank I thought the first line in the loop solution is a typo and changed it to `trace$mark <- trace$id` but it gives a slightly different result.

Comment: Can labels repeat?

Comment: It's also not clear why the marks are decreasing after fifth row.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Mark column is the desired output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg label 42 is dependent on label 45 which has id 4

Comment: @Frank labels can repeat. But we can select the most recent one

Comment: @Saltaf You example is not reproducible. There is no such thing as `trace$mark <- trace<-id` Also, fixing to `trace$mark <- trace$id` doesn't match your desired result.

Comment: @DavidArenburg There was a typo, corrected now.

Comment: Your loop still gives a different output for the seventh row. Also, in case labels repeat, which id should be taken, the last one?

Comment: I think it would help if you extend the example to cover the case of repeats.

Comment: Unclear question and the example you provided does not seem to cover the situation you described in the question.

Comment: @DavidArenburg edited examples/descitption to cover repeat labels

Comment: @Frank I have updated to cover that case

Comment: @Ouistiti The earlier example was covering the case I guess. I have updated it if it works for you now and edited the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
# clean up OP's example
trace[, mark := NULL ]

# lookup label
trace[, mark := 
  trace[.(dep = dep, id = id), on=.(label = dep, id < id), mult="last", x.id]
]

# if not found, use current id
trace[is.na(mark), mark := id ]

    id dep label mark
 1:  1  -1    99    1
 2:  2  45    40    2
 3:  3  40    43    2
 4:  4  47    45    4
 5:  5   0    47    5
 6:  6  45    42    4
 7:  7  43    48    3
 8:  8  42    45    6
 9:  9  45    52    8
10: 10  45    67    8
```

*How it works*

- `x[i, on=, mult=, j]` is a join.
- Each row of `i` is looked up in `x`.
- If multiple rows of `i` match a row of `x`, `mult=` determines what happens.
- The `x.*` prefix in `x.id` indicates which table it is taken from.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to track multiple row matches? For example, is it possible to have the following output (or something similar) where the last and second last entries have multiple dependencies, so instead of having 8 in the mark column, they have 4 and 8?

Comment: @Saltaf You mean like the string "4, 8"? If so, I think you might want `mult="all"` and then change `x.id` to `toString(x.id)` or something along those lines.

Comment: This results in the following for each mark, Any idea?
 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
...
 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You could post it as a new question, maybe.

Comment: posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576820/join-in-data-table-with-multiple-matches