# Join in data.table with multiple matches

Tags: r, data.table

I posted a question earlier about joining columns in data.table, where one column (dep) has the dependence information of an entry . So entry 3 is dependent on a record with label '40'. Then the 'match' column is assigned the id value of the label on which an entry depends. The question is posted here : [Comparing columns uptill certain index in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448169/comparing-columns-uptill-certain-index-in-r)

```
library(data.table)
trace <- data.table(id=1:10, dep=c(-1,45,40,47,0,45,43,42,45,45), 
label=c(99,40,43,45,47,42,48,45,52,67), mark=rep("",10))
   id dep label mark
1:  1  -1    99      
2:  2  45    40    
3:  3  40    43     
4:  4  47    45    
5:  5  0     47     
6:  6  45    42    
7:  7  43    48  
8:  8  42    45     
9:  9  45    52    
10: 10  45   67
```

would result in

```
    id dep label mark
1:  1  -1    99  1    
2:  2  45    40  2  
3:  3  40    43  2   
4:  4  47    45  4  
5:  5  0     47  5   
6:  6  45    42  4  
7:  7  43    48  3
8:  8  42    45  6   
9:  9  45    52  8  
10: 10  45   67  8
```

The following solution worked for me:

```
trace[, mark := trace[.(dep = dep, id = id), on=.(label = dep, id < id), mult="last", x.id]]

# if not found, use current id
trace[is.na(mark), mark := id ]
```

For the above case, for duplicates we were using the most recent match.
However, if instead of matching to last entry if I want to keep all matches, is there a way get an output similar to this (where last and second last entries have multiple dependencies):

```
   id dep label mark
1:  1  -1    99  1    
2:  2  45    40  2  
3:  3  40    43  2   
4:  4  47    45  4  
5:  5  0     47  5   
6:  6  45    42  4  
7:  7  43    48  3
8:  8  42    45  6   
9:  9  45    52  4,8  
10: 10  45   67  4,8
```

I am not that concerned about the format in which these dependencies are recorded. A slight modification of the earlier solution using mult="all",

```
trace[, mark := trace[.(dep = dep, id = id), on=.(label = dep, id < id), mult="all", toString(x.id)]]
```

results in this

```
 id dep label                                   mark
 1:  1  -1    99 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
 2:  2  45    40 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
 3:  3  40    43 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
 4:  4  47    45 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
 5:  5   0    47 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
 6:  6  45    42 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
 7:  7  43    48 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
 8:  8  42    45 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
 9:  9  45    52 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
10: 10  45    67 NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 4, 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, slight modification:

```
trace[, mark := trace[.(dep = dep, id = id), on=.(label = dep, id < id), 
  if (all(is.na(x.id))) NA_character_ else toString(x.id), by=.EACHI]$V1 ]

# if not found, use current id
trace[is.na(mark), mark := as.character(id) ]
```

It uses `as.character(id)` because `mark` is now a string variable.

To see how the `by=.EACHI` works, try running this part on its own:

```
trace[.(dep = dep, id = id), on=.(label = dep, id < id), 
  if (all(is.na(x.id))) NA_character_ else toString(x.id), by=.EACHI]
```

---

*Comments.* I expect this will not scale up well for larger tables. Also, the column no longer matches `id`'s type, so it cannot be used for merging, etc. A `list`-class column would have the same problem:

```
trace[, mark := trace[.(dep = dep, id = id), on=.(label = dep, id < id), 
  list(list(na.omit(x.id))), by=.EACHI]$V1 ]

# if not found, use current id
trace[lengths(mark) == 0L, mark := as.list(id)]
```

Comment: It worked for the normal test cases. But for actual million line record -- as you mentioned -- does not work.